# How to display the input's filename in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following object:

```
 "file": "https://www.example.com/file.zip",
```

Which I set like this:

```
$scope.building.file
```

and display like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" ng-model="building.file">
```

`ng-model="{{building.file}}` this part, though, doesn't work. How can I display the name of the file in that input file tag?

Answer (score 1):

you could create a directive handle this stuff there.

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

 angular
   .module('testApp')
   .directive('testFileUpload', testFileUpload);

 function testFileUpload(){
   return {
     scope: true,        //create a new scope and prototypically inherits from parent scope
     link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
       el.bind('change', function (event) {
         var files = event.target.files;
         //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element
         for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
           //emit event upward
           scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] });
         }
       });
     }
   };
 }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! How to use that directive in the HTML?

Comment: the normal way <test-file-upload type="file" on-change="bounce()"/>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" ng-model="{{building.file}}">
```

It should be:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" ng-model="building.file">
```

The name of the selected file shows even if you don't add ng-model.

Comment: Oh, yea that was a typo. But the name isn't being displayed even if I remove the curly braces.